# JavaDoc for joint java + groovy project

Tags: java, groovy, javadoc

I have a project that uses Java and Groovy intermixed. This works very well.

However, I want to create the javadoc for this. I know the javadoc creation for plain java projects. But for a combination of Groovy and Java, I have not found such a tool. Is there something out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is a tool (unimaginatively) named [Groovydoc](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t102917.html), which works by way of an [Ant task](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovydoc+Ant+task).

As far as I see, it also works as a drop-in replacement for javadoc on Java classes, so I suspect it would work on a mixed Java/Groovy project.

Comment: Thanks. This works. However, the Groovydoc Output is quite strange as the Classes are put in the default folder. Have to look at the options of the ANT task in more detail.